# How to set base URL while loading an URL to the WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, mraid

I am using WebView with the need of providing an access from HTML to javascript file located in raw resources. I can simply do it while loading HTML page from data with:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/raw/", getHtml(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

This way a call in loaded HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mraid.js"></script>
```

leads to `mraid.js` located under res/raw folder.

Question is, is there an easy way to set the base URL similarly while loading the page from external URL to achieve same effect? Unfortunatelly I see no kind of `WebView.loadUrlWithBaseUrl` method. 

Do I have to get the page with HTTP GET and than use `loadDataWithBaseURL' method like above?

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to load http://www.somepage.com, but you want requests with relative paths (like <script type="text/javascript" src="somecode.js"></script> in the head/body of the website you load from url) loads that script from local resources instead from http://www.somepage.com/somecode.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to set the base url. If you control the server you could just make it possible to specify an extra param that will add a `<base href="file:///android_res/raw/" />` tag.

Otherwise you could use [shouldInterceptRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) to serve a local resource instead of a remote one. (NOTE: mind the threads!)

Answer (score -2):

Try this-

```
  mWebview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webviewNews);
            mWebview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
            mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
            mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
            mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().supportZoom();
            mWebview.canGoBack();
            mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
```